# Rails: Complete object displayed instead of parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web app that displays `questions` with `options`. The problem is for the `options` it is displaying whole object along with the `body` parameter of the object. I do not know what is happening here. Is it something related to `serializing` and `deserializing`?

**index.html.erb**

```
 <tbody>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= question.body %></td>
        <td><%= question.user.email %></td>
        <td>
          <%= question.options.each do |p| %>  
            <%= radio_button_tag('option',p.id) %>
            <%= p.body %>
          <% end %>

        </td>

        <td><%= link_to 'Show', question %></td>
        <% if current_user && current_user.admin %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(question) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>          
        <% end %>

      </tr>
      <tr>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**controller_params**

```
private

    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end


    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:body, options_attributes: [:body])
    end
```

**model**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :options, dependent: :delete_all, :autosave => true
  validates_length_of :options, maximum: 4
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: `<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>`  Executes the ruby code within the brackets. You need to update `<%= question.options.each do |p| %>` to `<% question.options.each do |p| %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= question.options.each do |p| %>  
  <%= radio_button_tag('option',p.id) %>
  <%= p.body %>
<% end %>
```

Your problem is with this block. Your first part of ERB is telling the view to render `question.options.each` as well as the followowing HTML, resulting in the objects themselves being rendered. Changing to:

```
<% question.options.each do |p| %>  
  <%= radio_button_tag('option',p.id) %>
  <%= p.body %>
<% end %>
```

Will fix your issue.

Comment: Oh got it! Thanks!